# Stop Improving troops clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I start an improvement of a troop in clash of clans, and I want to stop it, is there any way to stop the improvement like we do with buildings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the wiki,

“ You cannot cancel the research while it is in progress, but you can immediately complete the upgrade. There are two methods to do so: using Gems, or with the relevant Magic Items (a Book of Fighting for troops, a Book of Spells for spells; a Book of Everything can be used for either).”

Comment: Thank you for your answer, next time I should to be careful when I start a research. sorry I can't uv your answer I need to points ;)